# Domain specific security for third party API

Tags: java, rest, api, oauth, restful-authentication

I have created a third party api(REST) that I wanted to make public but is only allowed to be accessed from a specific domain. How do I perform domain specific authentication/authorization?

For example, I have an api running on domain say mydomain.com and I wanted to create a JS widget that calls this api, but the widget is used in a different domain say otherdomain.com. How do I make sure only otherdomain.com has access to my api and it is not accessible from say anotherdomain.com.

I could use a api-key to authenticate the api, but I am not sure if that is secure enough as anyone who has access to source of otherdomain.com can copy the script and the api-key and try to access api directly. How can I avoid these kind of security holes.

Using mechanisms like Oauth2 may not help as there is no involvement of a user in this case and hence cannot do user authentication by getting user credentials.

Another idea would be to check for origin header, but it can simply be mocked as well using some reset clients I suppose(or am I wrong in this case)?

Please suggest some ideas to tackle this scenario.